# Function reference enclosed within angle brackets by dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am a beginning python programmer and trying to learn the nuances in the language. I was trying out the types of objects that can be stored inside the values key in a `dict` structure. Here goes my sample code:

```
  myMap = {'a':1,'b':hash}
  def myFun (a,b):
      return a + b
  myMap['c']=myFun
  myMap
```

And here is the output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': <function hash(obj, /)>, 'c': <function __main__.myFun(a, b)>}
```

I want to know why the function reference is enclosed by angle brackets. I have an inkling that this may be due to some resemblance to C code, but I am not able to get a definite answer. I read somewhere that this indicates that a function is a “special” object. But a more elaborate answer would be very helpful. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle brackets are typically used to denote part of the output that is related not to values themselves but rather to metadata related to the values.

In your case - there is no good way to represent a function in Python without providing its definition. However, `<function __main__.myFun(a, b)>` is a good way to print information *referring* to the function by providing its name and parameters.

There is no relation to C code other than maybe some convention but I am not aware of any.

Printing in the console of the representation of values of more complex objects in Python is handled by special ("magic") function [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) or `__str__` [depending on the situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr).